# How to send ^] from terminal to server using ZOC or Putty

Tags: keyboard, terminal, putty, telnet

I am connected via SSH to a remote Linux server and start a telnet session there.

In order to get to the telnet menu I need to send a  <kbd>^]</kbd> character.

The problem is, that I'm sitting on a Windows machine, the terminal emulator is [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) or [ZOC Terminal](https://www.emtec.com/zoc/).

I am also on a German keyboard, i.e. I need to press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> to get the `]` character.  Pressing it together with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key does noting (I googled and found that <kbd>AltGr</kbd> simulates <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> so it's not much of a surprise).

I can switch to U.S. keyboard and it works, but how do I send it from a native keyboard (preferably from ZOC, I'm only including Putty because more people seem to know it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Putty and ZOC you can press Ctrl+5 (they understand Ctrl+2 ... Ctrl+7 for the arcane control codes, this is an old DEC feature from the VT220 days).

Also, in Putty you can press the combo from the U.S. keyboard (Ctrl and whatever key is left of the Enter key on your keyboard in the place where the U.S. keyboard has the "]" key).

And of course, in both you can use the keyboard remap feature to put "^]" on any convenient key.